# Ionic datetime picker numbers in Arabic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I need to know if anyone ever implemented datetime picker in Arabic? or any other language. I need to change the numbers in different language like year 2019 will be change to ( ٢٠١٩)

Answer (score 0):

You only can define the names of months using properties of [ion-datetime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime):

[image]

```
<ion-datetime
  name="date"
  done-text="Done"
  placeholder="Date"
  pickerFormat="DD/MMM/YYYY"
  displayFormat="DD/MMMM/YYYY"
  monthNames="JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, 
  SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER"
  monthShortNames="jan, feb, mar, abr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec">
</ion-datetime>
```

You can replace the names by for the numbers of the months on arabic, but actually ion-datetime don't have support to change the numbers directly, but ionic are Javascript so you can add other library of datetime picker that can support arabic format.